# Is there a way to automatically detect the minimum required BR2_TARGET_ROOTFS_EXT2_SIZE in Buildroot?

Tags: buildroot

I'm making a "big" non-embedded image intended for simulation instead of real devices, and I keep hitting the error:

```
*** Maybe you need to increase the filesystem size (BR2_TARGET_ROOTFS_EXT2_SIZE)
```

and then I have to do a `du` on `output/target` to find out how big I have to make `BR2_TARGET_ROOTFS_EXT2_SIZE`.

Is there a way to automate this, or a decent workaround?

Some workarounds I'm considering:

- put the big stuff under 9p: https://superuser.com/questions/628169/how-to-share-a-directory-with-the-host-without-networking-in-qemu
- use CPIO and `-initrd`

http://lists.busybox.net/pipermail/buildroot/2018-March/215622.html

Answer (score 2):

http://lists.busybox.net/pipermail/buildroot/2018-March/215636.html says that:

> No, becaaue it is not reliable, see commit:
>
> ```
> c6bca8cef fs/ext2: Remove support for auto-calculation of rootfs size
> ```
>
> In the end, it does not make sense to do auto-calculation, because on an
>   embedded device, you have to now the layout and size of your storage.
>   So, you know what size you want your ext filesystem to be.

So it is fundamentally not possible / worth for Buildroot to do it reliably.

https://github.com/buildroot/buildroot/commit/c6bca8cef0310bc649240b451989457ce94a8358

I have then searched a bit further, and came across: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/353156/how-to-calculate-the-correct-size-of-a-loopback-device-filesystem-image-for-debo which suggests  `resize2fs -M` + sparse files might be a possibility.

libguestfs can also minimize image sizes automatically as demonstrated at https://serverfault.com/questions/246835/convert-directory-to-qemu-kvm-virtual-disk-image/916697#916697 and is exposes a `vfs-minimum-size` function: http://libguestfs.org/guestfish.1.html#vfs-minimum-size